# How to read rows from a datatable (or the whole table at once) into a new database with a new connection?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, datatable

I'm working in C# to combine queries from separate databases into one query/database. So far, I have queried what I need from the first connection (let's call it Connection1) and filled in the datatable

```
OleDbCommand dt = new OleDbCommand("SELECT blah FROM blah", DBConn.Connection1);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(dt);
adapter1.Fill(dt);
```

Now, I need to read this datatable into a database with a brand new connection (call it Connection2). After this I will need to combine this database with the result of the other query in Connection2.

How can I go about reading this datatable into a brand new connection so that all the data in the datatable can be used with that through Connection 2?

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like an INSERT INTO... (values) (SELECT...) should do the trick. Basically a subquery selecting what you want to insert. Didn't understand the 'other query in connection2' comment. Might want to clarify your request. Good luck.

Comment: I must not understand your question, but can't you just create another new connection. How about showing us the rest of your code?

Comment: @user3741598 : I'm a complete newbie to C# so I haven't really tried much. Plenty of Googleing yielded more questions than answers.       Basically I have 2 separate queries coming from 2 different connections. I simply need a way to be able to take the data from Query 1 by Connection 1 and be able to join it with the data I will be getting from Query 2 by Connection 2

Comment: @rontornambe: What is shown above is more or less all of my code at this point. I'm not trying to create a new connection. I'm simply trying to get the query from the first connection to play nice with the upcomming query from the second connection. It was my understanding that I would need to take the results of the first query and transform the datatable in a way to make it readable with the second connection. That is what I am trying to do

Comment: Are the tables from each database (I am assuming you have two separate databases) identically defined? Do you just want to combine the data from each database table into a single table? How is DBConn.Connection1 defined?

Comment: it is very simple , you have a `datatable` , use a loop, read the `datarow` one by one and insert the data in 2nd database or you can use `batch insert` to insert data or if you've some conditions for data , you can also use `sql transactions`, it all depends on your requirements.